# How to read the tasks (Foreground App) in android L

Tags: android, task, android-5.0-lollipop, deprecated

I want to know the Application which is running in foreground from a service.Since getrunningTasks is deprecated from lollipop.what are the other approaches.I don't want to use usagestatsmanager and getRunningAppProcesses() API.

Comment: Apps are not supposed to have that information. That's why they deprecated it (and limited its output in Lollipop).

Comment: so...there is no way of reading the tasks??.